# How get information from variable web page with use node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, get

There is a web page. In page source have script:

```
<script>
        var important = [{....}];
</script>
```

How get information from this variable with use node.js???

***In a similar situation***, when information was in function:

```
$(function() {
    _very.important ([{....}]);
```

I use code:

```
var cloudscraper = require("cloudscraper");    
cloudscraper.get("link" , function(error, response, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('ERRRRRRROR');
      } else {
        var info = JSON.parse(data.split("_very.important(")[1].split(")")[0]);
```

***But, I dont know how work with this problem.***

```
    var important = [{....}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a id to the script like     `<script id="script">` and get the details through innerHTML like

```
    document.getElementById('script').innerHTML
```

Comment: This is node.js?

Comment: And in page <script>   var important = [{....}]; </script> , and you write : <script id="script"> this is not true